# I am working on the following query, but I get the error listed below

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Here is my query:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[GetTotalComp]
     (@bonus DECIMAL, @empsalary MONEY)
RETURNS INT
AS
-- Returns total compensation
BEGIN
DECLARE @totalComp money   

IF @bonus is NULL
set @totalComp=@empsalary
else If (@empsalary>50000) and (@empsalary<=100000)
set @totalComp=@empsalary+(@bonus*@empsalary)
else if (@empsalary>100000)
set @totalComp=@empsalary + 2*(@bonus*@empsalary)

RETURN @totalComp;
END;



declare @param varchar(25)
set @param=392

IF @param=0
select LName,Fname, Isnull(Name,'Unassinged') as DeptName,'$' + convert(varchar,dbo.GetTotalComp(d.bonus,e.salary),-1) as TotalComp from Emp e
left join EmpInDept ed on e.empid=ed.empid
left join Dept d on ed.deptid=d.deptid
ELSE
select LName,Fname, Isnull(Name,'Unassinged') as DeptName,'$' + convert(varchar,dbo.GetTotalComp(d.bonus,e.salary),-1) as TotalComp from Emp e
left join EmpInDept ed on e.empid=ed.empid
left join Dept d on ed.deptid=d.deptid
where d.deptid=@param
```

I get this error message:

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Procedure GetTotalComp, Line 19 [Batch Start Line 4]
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'THEN'.

Comment: Add the query **to the question** - don't post it in a comment!

Comment: Your (now deleted) "answer" doesn't contain a `THEN` other than the comment "THEN the query:". Reasons not to use images are [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/92546). Please read [this](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question.

Comment: is `THEN the query:` really part of the code? It seems to be, and would be the obvious culprit of the error.

Comment: Sorry, I deleted it (THEN the query:) and I get this error: Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Procedure GetTotalComp, Line 19 [Batch Start Line 4]
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'declare'.

Comment: How about you update your question to reflect your actual code. No comments in it or any of the like. Your question still shows `Then the query:` as if it were part of the code. If these are two groups of statements being run independanlty of one another, then remove the four spaces in front of `THEN the query: ` so it shows as regular text.

Answer (score 0):

In general, queries shouldn't also create a function like in your script.
However, if you really need this in one script, then you need to add the keyword [`GO`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/sql-server-utilities-statements-go)  between the query and the create function script.

Also, since your script is creating a function, this mean it will only run once, because it will say the function already exist the second time. So I've added extra code to for that.

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.GetTotalComp') IS NOT NULL 
     DROP FUNCTION dbo.GetTotalComp
GO

CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[GetTotalComp]
     (@bonus DECIMAL, @empsalary MONEY)
RETURNS INT
AS
-- Returns total compensation
BEGIN
DECLARE @totalComp money   

IF @bonus is NULL
set @totalComp=@empsalary
else If (@empsalary>50000) and (@empsalary<=100000)
set @totalComp=@empsalary+(@bonus*@empsalary)
else if (@empsalary>100000)
set @totalComp=@empsalary + 2*(@bonus*@empsalary)

RETURN @totalComp;
END;

GO  --THE KEYWORD YOU WERE MISSING HERE

declare @param varchar(25)
set @param=392

IF @param=0
select LName,Fname, Isnull(Name,'Unassinged') as DeptName,'$' + convert(varchar,dbo.GetTotalComp(d.bonus,e.salary),-1) as TotalComp from Emp e
left join EmpInDept ed on e.empid=ed.empid
left join Dept d on ed.deptid=d.deptid
ELSE
select LName,Fname, Isnull(Name,'Unassinged') as DeptName,'$' + convert(varchar,dbo.GetTotalComp(d.bonus,e.salary),-1) as TotalComp from Emp e
left join EmpInDept ed on e.empid=ed.empid
left join Dept d on ed.deptid=d.deptid
where d.deptid=@param
```

Answer (score 0):

I would make this an inline table valued function instead of a scalar function. It is more performant and more flexible.

```
create function GetTotalComp
(
    @bonus decimal
    , @empsalary money
) returns table as return

    select TotalComp = 
    case when @bonus is null 
            then @empsalary
        when @empsalary > 50000 and @empsalary <= 100000
            then @empsalary + (@bonus * @empsalary)
        when @empsalary > 100000
            then @empsalary + 2 * (@bonus * @empsalary)
        else
            NULL
        end
```

Then your code to use this could be greatly simplified also. Something like this.

```
declare @param varchar(25)
set @param=392

select LName
    , Fname
    , Isnull(Name,'Unassinged') as DeptName
    ,'$' + convert(varchar(10), c.TotalComp , -1) as TotalComp 
from Emp e
left join EmpInDept ed on e.empid = ed.empid
left join Dept d on ed.deptid = d.deptid
cross apply dbo.GetTotalComp(d.bonus, e.salary) c
where d.deptid = d.deptid
    OR @param = 0
```

Comment: Thank you all for your help, I do appreciate it!